# Interpreting the statement

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, logic, proof-verification, quantifiers

Just started quantifiers, and I'm having some trouble with interpreting this.

Here's what I understand:

For every Epsilon $> 0$, there exists a Delta $> 0$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

The antecedent of the implication is false, because there is no Delta that is always greater than $x$.

The precedent of the implication is also false, because not every Epsilon greater than $0$ is also greater than $x^2 -1$ for any $x$.

So the statement is false. Is my logic sound? I'm not sure if I'm reading this right.

Comment: Do you know what your statement *means* though? That is, besides the strict logical interpretation, do you know what is being communicated?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your difficulty arises from a shortage of parentheses in the formula.  I think the formula was intended to be 
$$
(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in\mathbb R)\Big([0<|x-1|<\delta]\implies [|x^2-1|<\varepsilon]\Big).
$$
That is, the quantifiers at the beginning apply to the whole implication, not just to its antecedent.  This is also how the two answers preceding mine (by Ahmed and Michael Cotton) interpreted the formula.

Answer (score 0):

$(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(∃δ > 0)(∀x ∈ R):0 <| x − 1 |< δ \implies | x^2 − 1 |< ε$

I believe you read it wrong. It should be:

For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all real numbers $x$ it holds that
if $0<|x-1|<\delta$ then $|x^2-1|<\varepsilon$. Here $x$ is just not a real number but a real number that can be chosen that close to $1$ so that $|x^2-1|<\varepsilon$ - how close to zero you first choose $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a neat opportunity for a "mini **real analysis** lesson." Your formula was most certainly wrong, and Andreas kindly fixed it:
$$
(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in\mathbb R)(0<|x-1|<\delta\to|x^2-1|<\varepsilon).
$$
What you have here is actually a particular instance of the formal definition of a limit at a real number being used. Huh? Yes, consider the following definition of a limit at a real number from James Stewart's *Calculus* textbook.

---

**Definition:** Let $f$ be a function defined on some open interval that contains the number $a$, except possibly at $a$ itself. Then we say that the **limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is $L$**, and we write
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L
$$
if for every number $\epsilon>0$ there is a number $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|f(x)-L|<\epsilon\qquad\text{whenever}\qquad 0<|x-a|<\delta.
$$

---

Pay very close attention to how this definition is worded. Using universal quantifiers, we may represent it as follows:
$$
(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(0<|x-a|<\delta\to|f(x)-L|<\epsilon).
$$
Now consider what Andreas wrote:
$$
(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in\mathbb R)(0<|x-1|<\delta\to|x^2-1|<\varepsilon).
$$
What does this *mean* in the context of your question? By George, you are actually considering the **formal** statement of the claim
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}(x^2-1)=0.
$$
This is what your statement *means*, and it is not false. I will outline a formal proof below that follows the formal definition of a limit.

---

**Claim:**
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}(x^2-1)=0.
$$

*Proof.* Given $\epsilon>0$, we need $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-1|<\delta$, then
$$
|(x^2-1)-0|=|x^2-1|=|(x-1)(x+1)|<\epsilon.
$$
Notice that if $|x-1|<1$, then
$$
-1<x-1<1\Longrightarrow 1<x+1<3\Longrightarrow |x+1|<3.
$$
So take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\right\}$. Then
\begin{align}
0<|x-1|<\delta &\Longleftrightarrow |(x-1)(x+1)|\\[1em]
               &\leq |3(x-1)|\\[1em]
               &= 3\cdot|x-1|\\[1em]
               &< 3\delta\\[1em]
               &\leq \epsilon.
\end{align}
Thus, $\lim_{x\to 1}(x^2-1)=0$ by the definition of a limit. $\Box$

Comment: The simple misunderstanding that Blass pointed out was the whole question, really. So this is all a bit much.

Comment: @MichaelCotton It helps to see that the statement actually means something. It is a true statement when considered correctly using quantifiers. "All a bit much"--not sure what the point of that is. My answer gives a framework through which to view future problems not just validation of a particular instance. I think it is just the right amount, not too much and not too little.

Comment: You don't think that an $\varepsilon\delta$-proof that $x^2$ is continuous at $1$ is a bit much? Because it really is.

Comment: @MichaelCotton *Ibidem*. Also, I did not prove that $x^2$ is continuous at $1$; I proved that $\lim_{x\to 1}(x^2-1)=0$.

Comment: One way to say a real function $f(x)$ is continuous at a value $a$ is $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$, or equivalently $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(x)-f(a))=0$. The $\varepsilon\delta$-definition of continuity at a point is precisely the same translation of this limit. So they really are the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelCotton You are purposefully being difficult. The three conditions for continuity are clear: 1) $f(a)$ is defined, 2) $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists or is finite, and 3) $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$. The OP posted a question that was *precisely* equivalent, when corrected, to a claim about a limit. Your comments do not add anything at all to the discussion, and I find it odd that you would harp on an answer that provided more than just a correction to the OP's problem but a thorough answer to what the problem actually meant.

Comment: The first two parts of that definition are redundant.

Comment: @MichaelCotton It's the [standard](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/continuitydirectory/Continuity.html) way the idea is expressed. I suggest you add something constructive or MSE may not be the place for you.

Comment: It's probably the most common way to introduce it in textbooks because it keeps students from trying to say something is continuous "because undefined = undefined". But that doesn't actually mean it's necessary. And this also doesn't change what was said earlier. The two interpretations were the same, and it's important for building intuition to recognize that.

Answer (score -2):

You could read the implication as:

$|x^2 -1|<\varepsilon\:$ *whenever* $\:
|x-1|<\delta$

which seems just fine.

With the quantifiers, this whole thing just says the function $x^2$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Added note: See Andreas Blass' answer. I was assuming the quantifiers applied to the entire implication. Depending on the text it's from, that's probably what is intended.